# How to safly check the uninitialized value from Deserialization

Tags: c#, serialization

I am creating a DataContract class to be used in deserialize from a string. I read some article and find out that, I can write a OnDeserialized method, which will be called after deserialization, before returns the object. This is what it looks like of my class.

It works fine, if any member is NOT in the stream. How ever, my question is, in case the member is NOT in the stream, who can gurantee those uninitialized values are 0, DateTime.MinValue and null, respectively?

Also, if a int member do have a value of 0, how do I know it is from the stream or not initialized?

```
[DataContract]
public class MyData
{
    [DataMember]
    public int MemberA { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime MemberB { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string MemberC { get; set; }

    [OnDeserialized]
    void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext c)
    {
        if (MemberA == 0)
            MemberA = 100;
        if (MemberB == DateTime.MinValue)
            MemberB = DateTime.Now;
        if (MemberC == null)
            MemberC = "MemberC";
    }
}
```

I am looking for a better approach, something like

```
if (NotInitialized(MemberA))
    MemberA = xxx;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using a nullable type, which will automatically be set to `null` if the data is missing during deserialisation:

```
[DataMember]
public int? MemberA { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public DateTime? MemberB { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public string? MemberC { get; set; }
```

Note the addition of `?` to each value type which indicates that it can also be `null`.

To ascertain whether these have values is easy:

```
if (MemberA.HasValue)
{
    // Value = MemberA.Value;
    ... do something
}
```

You can also ensure that the member is not output if you serialise the class again using attributes on `DataMember`:

```
[DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public int? MemberA { get; set; }
```

This means that `MemberA` will be omitted entirely from your serialised results if it has a `null` value.

Comment: So in case there is no value from stream, those nullable type will be guaranteed to be null? Can you show me a reference?

Comment: So if `MemberA.HasValue` is false then the value is `null`. This works for `int`s as well so it will not be `0` in the case of being missing from your data stream.

Comment: IsRequired = false means, if this value is null, then do not serialize?
if EmitDefaultValue = true, how to set the default value?

Comment: So if `EmitDefaultValue = true` then _[the] default value for a member should be generated in the serialization stream_. So for `int` it will be `0`, and so on.  The value is whatever the default for that value type is.